# Confused about this 'lab'

Tags: python

Just here to ask if someone can answer this. It's a school lab and I don't quite understand it and I'm on vacation so I can't ask my teacher haha. Python.

`Create a list of 10,000 random numbers from 1 to 6. This should take one line of code. Use the function you created earlier in the lab.)
Print the count of 1 through 6. (That is, print the number of times 1 appears in the 10,000. And then do the same for 2-6.)
Print the average of all 10,000 random numbers.`

Try to make it high-school coding friendly. Thank you.

Comment: Google "random integer python".

Comment: I guess you missed the part where you had to physically go to the lab earlier. I don't think we can help with that.

Comment: Is not a physical lab. This is computer programming lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description you gave, the desired output appears to be:

- the count (0..10000) of each number from one to six; and
- the average of all numbers.

So you'll probably want something like this:

```
Number 1 occurred 1662 times.
Number 2 occurred 1676 times.
Number 3 occurred 1600 times.
Number 4 occurred 1696 times.
Number 5 occurred 1696 times.
Number 6 occurred 1670 times.
The average of all numbers was 3.5098.
```

That *should* be enough information for you to start coding. Feel free to come back and ask us specific questions about whatever code you come up with, we'll be happy to help.

It may help to start with the following pseudo-code and work from there:

```
list = generate10000Numbers1To6()
create array count[1..6], initialise to zero
for number in list:
    increment count[number]
sum = 0
for number in 1..6:
    print "Number ", number, " occurred ", count[number], " times."
    add count[number] * number to sum
print "The average of all numbers was ", sum / 10000, "."
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'll go test :D

Comment: Very stumped... do not know how to search for each element in the list and check if it's  in the range of the number I select.

Comment: @Terrace, my suggestion is that you write the code to generate the list then spend some time googling for "python process list count" or something similar. When you have some (any) code, we can offer more targeted help.

Answer (score -2):

Oneway of doing is:

```
import random
listOfRandomNumbers = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    listOfRandomNumbers.append(a)
average = sum(listOfRandomNumbers)/len(listOfRandomNumbers)
print("The average of all numbers",average)
frequencyOfEachWord = []
for i in range(1,7):
    f = listOfRandomNumbers.count(i)
    frequencyOfEachWord.append(f)
    print("Number ", i ," occured ", f ,"times")
```